# Error: not found: value SparkSession

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I just followed the getting [started page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) of Spark and tried to run the simpleApp.

```
My Spark version : 2.3
Scala version in REPL: 2.11.8
```

This is the build.sbt file:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"
```

When I run sbt package, First I get some of conflicts warnings. Then there's this error

> not found: value SparkSession
>   [error]     val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()

What could I be missing? In the target folder, it shows scala 2.12. I wonder why.

Comment: Are you familiar with sbt? Is your project structured correctly? Maybe your `build.sbt` is not where it should be (root folder of your project).